# Error while publishing to Weblogic Server 11gR1

Tags: ejb, jndi, executable-jar, weblogic11g, ejb-jar.xml

I am receiving the following error. What does this mean and how to fix it?

```
       Unable to deploy EJB : xxxEJB from xx.JAR
    Error deployin gthe EJB 'xxxEJB, the JNDI name 'xxxEJB' is already in use. 
You must set a different JNDI name in weblogic-ejb-jar.xml deployment descriptor or corresponding annotation for this EJB before it can be deployed.
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Have you tried to remove cache from %BEA_HOME\user_projects\domains\yourdomain\servers\yourserver\tmp ? If you are using eclipse, try to clean project also.

Comment: The error is clear. 
The JNDI name is made of EJB's mappedName + the name of its remote interface. "Weblogic-ejb-jar.xml" overwrites this (if you have any). Have you deployed this EJB in a jar file with a different name?

Comment: If you are using Weblogic + Eclipse, check the Published Modules under your Weblogic Server. Remove conflicting ear if there is one.